# Spring boot services communication

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing services in Spring boot.

So lets say I have 2 services - A , B.

Service A has one API A1() which returns some class customObject say

```
class CustomObject{
   int id;
   String name;
     .... +n more properties
}
```

So from my API, I return the object of CustomObject and corresponding JSON has been returned from my API.(Using @RestController )

Now Service B is calling this API. So It calls A1() api of service A(Using RestTemplate / Feign Client), gets the JSON, to access it now, I have to create CustomObject in Service B also to map JSON to Object.

This is the issue. I don't want my services to be dependent on each other but here customObject is getting created in both the services. If any changes are made to CustomObject in Service A, then same changes needs to be incorporated in Service B.

SO what should be the better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create simple project, where collect your DTO classes. Push it to you maven repo (nexus for example). Then add it to dependencies in each project.